# Any further improvement I can make in my code below?

Tags: c#-4.0, image-processing, image-manipulation

This is the code I cam up with to generate square thumbnail in C#

I havent't code this type of thing before. 
Since this code will be used heavily, I am checking with you before I put this in production.

Do you see anything bad or can be improved further?

Basically I have a set of thumbnails sitting in some folder.
Those thumbnails are not square and I need to make all of them square.
This will be called in a loop for each file in the folder.

This is how I call it:

```
SaveSquareThumb(75, "C:\storage\images\temp\thumbs", "C:\storage\images\thumbs");

public static void SaveSquareThumb(int squareSize, string sourcePath, string savePath)
        {
            using (Bitmap srcImage = new Bitmap(sourcePath))
            {
                int width = srcImage.Width;
                int height = srcImage.Height;

                int x = 0;
                int y = 0;

                //Determine dimensions of resized version of the image 
                if (width > height)
                {
                    width = (int)Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal((decimal)squareSize * ((decimal)width / (decimal)height)), 0);

                    height = squareSize;
                    // moves cursor so that crop is more centered 
                    x = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(((decimal)(width - height) / 2M)));
                }
                else if (height > width)
                {
                    height = (int)Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal((decimal)squareSize * ((decimal)height / (decimal)width)), 0);
                    width = squareSize;
                    // moves cursor so that crop is more centered 
                    y = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(((decimal)(height - width) / 2M)));
                }
                else
                {
                    width = squareSize;
                    height = squareSize;
                }

                // required in case thumbnail creation fails?
                Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort dummyCallback = new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);

                EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);
                ImageCodecInfo codecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
                EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
                encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;

                //get thumbnail from source image
                using (Image thumb = srcImage.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, null, System.IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    //Create a Crop Frame to apply to the Resized Image 
                    using (Bitmap myBitmapCropped = new Bitmap(squareSize, squareSize))
                    {
                        using (Graphics myGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmapCropped))
                        {
                            //Apply the Crop to the Resized Image 
                            myGraphic.DrawImage(thumb, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), x, y, width, height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                            //Save the Croped and Resized image as a new square thumnail 
                            myBitmapCropped.Save(savePath, codecInfo, encoderParams);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Probably belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First two items are most important, third and fourth are all about code readability:

1. Add input parameters validation
2. Consider how method should behave if any of path parameters is not found
3. You have multiple casts of `((decimal)squareSize)`, `((decimal)width)` consider single cast and store it in the new method level variables
4. You canset at the beginning of method default values for `width` and `height` to be equals to `squareSize` and then remove following code block:

```cs
   else
   {
      width = squareSize;
      height = squareSize;
   }
```